# git pull returns fatal: bad object refs/remotes/__init__.py

Tags: git

When I run `git pull` I see this message:

```
Auto empaquetado del repositorio en segundo plano para un performance óptimo.
Vea "git help gc" para limpieza manual.
warning: El último gc reportó lo siguiente. Por favor corrige la causa
y elimine .git/gc.log.
Limpieza automática no se realizará hasta que el archivo sea eliminado.

fatal: bad object refs/remotes/__init__.py
fatal: failed to run repack

Ya está actualizado.
```

I then run:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/__init__.py 
rm .git/gc.log
```

And after that `git pull` again, and I just see:

```
Auto empaquetado del repositorio en segundo plano para un performance óptimo.
Vea "git help gc" para limpieza manual.
Ya está actualizado.
```

Which seems to be nice, but If I do again `git gc`:

```
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/PLAT-88/__init__.py
fatal: failed to run repack
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Try `find .git/refs/remotes -name __init__.py` to find all of them. It seems some script creates these `__init__.py` at the wrong place. And try `git for-each-ref | grep __init__`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I run `find .git/refs/remotes -name __init__.py`and i get three files. If I do `git .git/refs/remotes/origin/PLAT-88/__init__.py | grep __init__`. I see: `git .... it's not a git command`

Comment: That's a very odd error. Is there a chance you've stored a Git repository in a cloud-synced folder?

Comment: i don't think so. The git repository is in a docker container. And the folder it's one created by me.